# downloading file with cURL from a deeper directory

Tags: curl

Likely a simple question, but this has me stumped.

I'm trying to issue a command line cURL statement on Linux to download a file from a remote server. The cURL makes the connection, and will do a directory listing.  It will also download files from the highest directory level. But i need to go one directory deeper for my file, and my request simply times out.

To summarize, this works: curl ftp://ftp.the.site.filename
This times out: curl ftp://ftp.the.site/directory/fileineed.txt

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In case it helps someone in the future, I figured out the correct code:  curl --ftp-method nocwd --request GET ftp://ftp.thesite.com/directory/fileineed.txt

Comment: feel free to post your solution as an answer